# BEST File Update Workflow Process?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, workflow, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

**SUMMARY:**

I need the **most efficient workflow** to individually edit over 200 files, and have them automatically disappear from the search results as they are updated.

**DETAILS:**

I am in the process of adding logging throughout a legacy system, and need to update over 200 files, each with their own custom code. I need to edit them one by one, and would like for the updated files to automatically disappear from my working search results after I have completed each one. The idea is to know how many and which ones still need to be updated as I slowly work through them all.

I already had to do something similar a few months ago, but on a much smaller scale, and I used an old-school HACK to do it. I did a search and replace for my keyword, and intentionally misspelled it. I then used the misspelled keyword for my search, and corrected it when editing each file, hence automatically removing it from the list. It "works", but is obviously a **TOTAL HACK**.

I recently started using **IntelliJ IDEA**, and am not yet familiar with the more advanced features like **Find in File Scopes**, **Search Structurally**, **Search Templates**, etc., but I am sure there ***HAS*** to be a "**correct**" way to do this in **IntelliJ**, and I just *don't know how*.

I am currently using "Find in Files" to work through the list, and recently found "All Changed Files" in the Scope list, which is actually the *EXACT OPPOSITE* of what I need. Is there a way to show "All ***UNCHANGED*** Files"??? That would work PERFECTLY in a pinch! But really, I would rather learn the ***CORRECT*** way to do this in **IntelliJ**.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) How do you use Find in Files right now? Would be super good to a see the screenshot of that (you can blur/redact private parts but still show the tools used). 2)  If you are using the "Find" functionality right now -- does this means that the changed code is no longer contains the searched phrase? P.S. There is no "Unchanged scope" -- simply because it makes little to no sense (IMO at least).